# Integral in vector form

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, notation

I have two **vectors** $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ and some function $f(x, k)$. So for example function $f$ can be evaluated at some point say $f(x_{1}, 10)$. Then I have an integral written $$\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}f(x,k)\ dx$$. I don't know how to calculate an integral written in a such form. So for example if $x$ is $2$-dimensional vector will it be $$\int_{x_{1,2}}^{x_{2,2}}\int_{x_{1,1}}^{x_{2,1}}f(x,k)\ dx_{1}dx_{2}$$? Please, help me to understand this notation.

My question closely relates to notation in the end of first page here where CV calculated http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~zlai/teaching/MicroTheory_Note8_Welfare.pdf

Comment: If I understand well, we have to search curves that connect this to vectors, imagine that they are vectors on such a plane. The nice thing is that it can, or cannot depends on the curve. Again, I don't know if I understand well your question.

Comment: Also I whant to add that f is function returning vector. My question closely relates to what is in http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~zlai/teaching/MicroTheory_Note8_Welfare.pdf in the end of the first page

Comment: ok, so it is a vector field. The answer is that. You have to use the concept of line integrals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could someone, please, provide an example of calculation for the case f(x,k)=(k*x_{1}*x_{2}, k/x_{1}-x_{2}) where integral limits are (1,1), (3,3) and k=5?

Comment: I recommend you to see this video: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/line_integrals_topic/line_integrals/v/introduction-to-the-line-integral